# Resuming an interrupted form submit without losing the "submit" button value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple function that intercepts a form submit event, displays a SweetAlert2 confirmation dialogue, and if the user confirms the form is submitted.

The function is something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.require-confirmation').submit(event => window.swalConfirm(event));
});
```

```js
window.swalConfirm = function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    Swal.fire().then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            e.target.submit();
        }
    })
};
```

This works as expected… in most cases. When the form has multiple submit buttons – for example:

```html
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add">Add</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="remove">Remove</button>
```

… the value of "action" is removed from the submitted form. Is there any way around this, like resuming the initial submit or something like that? Or is there no option but making the buttons change the value of a hidden input before submitting the form, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You gave the solution yourself

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />
<button type="button" class="action" value="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" class="action" value="remove">Remove</button>

$(function() {
  $('.action').on("click",function(e) {
    const parent = this.form;
    $("[name=action]").val(this.value);
    Swal.fire().then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        parent.submit();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: I knew that was an option, but I was wondering if there was an elegant way to just make the original submit proceed unaltered. Especially because, that way, I could make this a universal confirmation modal, where I would just add the class "require-confirmation" to the forms the submission of which I'd like to have confirmed. Thank you for your input, though!

Comment: There is no resume. You can use confirm which will pause and possibly cancel